# Elastic search is not returning the result python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search, and I am following the document to implement some feature,In each document of elastic search contains hashtag, count (no. of time that hashtag occurs) and then a list of postId which have the same hashtag. After inserting in elastic search, When I run

```
es.search(index="hashtags-python",body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})
```

it gave me result:

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'hashtags-python',
    '_type': 'post_hashtag',
    '_id': 'tKcCunoBeugv2TosQxgh',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'hastag': 'Costa Rica',
     'count': 1,
     'postIds': ['5f7c8ac6b8be7018ebc06842']}},
   {'_index': 'hashtags-python',
    '_type': 'post_hashtag',
    '_id': 'tacCunoBeugv2TosRxgM',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'hastag': 'mountain biking',
     'count': 1,
     'postIds': ['5f7c8ac6b8be7018ebc06842']}}]}}
```

If a new hashtag come then I have to check whether it exists or not if it does not exist then I will update the count and append that id in postIds. To search the tag my query is.

```
es.search(index="hashtags-python",body={"query":{"match":{"hashtag":"Costa Rica"}}})
```

and it is giving me the result:

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': None,
  'hits': []}}
```

Although the document is present

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in your field name,  in the response for the `match_all` query that you shared, the field name is `hastag`, not `hashtag`. Can you confirm the field name?

Comment: My bad that was the issue